# can't call django json view with angularjs

Tags: django, json, angularjs

i'm new in django and also in angularjs.
I wants to use Django for a REST api and angularjs for frontend view.

I have a django view that returns a json response:

```
class MyView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        data = serializers.serialize('json', MyModel.objects.order_by('name'))
        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')

    def options(self, request):
        response = HttpResponse()
        response['allow'] = ','.join(['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'options'])
        return response
```

calling

```
http://localhost:8000/myapp/myview
```

i get the right json response

If in an angularjs controller (controllers.js) i try to call that view like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.test = "Hola";
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    $http.get('http://localhost:8000/myapp/myview').success(function(data) {
      $scope.results = data;
      console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status) {
      $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
      $scope.status = status;
      console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```

"test" value is correctly printed in the template

in django log i have: "GET /myapp/myview/ HTTP/1.1" 200 853

but in angular i don't retrieve any data. If i put a break point in error method, i have data empty and status = 0.

Any hints?
Am i missing something?

Comment: Can you try to add a `console.log(data)` line below of `$scope.results = data;` line and say if you see data in console(firebug etc.)?

Comment: Can you show xhr request and response headers from web console?

Comment: Remove the last forward slash from this url `http://localhost:8000/myapp/myview/`

Comment: Can you post your URLconf just in case?

Comment: i removed last slash and added a console.log (catched in the error method).
in browser console i have this:
`GET http://localhost:8000/myapp/myview 200 OK 15ms
    (an empty string)`

Comment: my url conf row: `url(r'^myview', MyView.as_view(), name='myview'),`

Comment: Again, can you please put request & response headers from web console, so we have more details?

Comment: sorry, i forgot this..
`Response:
Content-Type application/json
Date Mon, 02 Sep 2013 07:46:05 GMT
Server WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.5`

`Request:
Accept application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Host localhost:8000
Origin http://127.0.0.1:9000
Referer http://127.0.0.1:9000/app/index.html`

Comment: Solved adding `response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` and `response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = ['POST','GET','OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'DELETE']` on my response before returning it, in django "get" method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been struggling with the same. The problem is with CORS. [The solution is here](https://www.vinta.com.br/blog/2015/django-cors/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8000/myapp/myview/').success(function(data)
```

The URL needs to drop the trailing /, then append .json. Like so:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8000/myapp/myview.json').success(function(data)
```

Comment: I tried also this, but i have same results: a 200 but an empty string

Comment: Post all the angular controller code, maybe you have missed injecting the $http service into the module.