# How do i render django json view with angularjs $resource?

Tags: django, angularjs

Just completed the Angularjs tutorial and now trying to integrate it with Django.

For my problem, i looked around and found a problem close to mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18563411/cant-call-django-json-view-with-angularjs) but the problem was never solved.

My django view;

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        data = serializers.serialize('json',Category.objects.all())
        return HttpResponse(data,content_type="application/json")
```

app.js

```
app.factory('categories',['$resource',function($resource){
  return $resource('/categories');
}]);


app.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope','categories',function($scope,categories){
  $scope.test="test";
  $scope.categories = category.query();
  });

}]);
```

calling the `\categories` i get the correct json response.

The test value renders fine but not the categories data is not rendering in view.

What am i not doing right, links are welcome too.

**SOLVED:** Check my answer.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546136/does-this-promise-look-correct/21547135#21547135

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of tinkering and headaches, figured it was because i was providing the wrong `url` to my `categories service`. Instead of `return $resource('/categories');` it should have been 'return $resource('/correct-url/categories');'. Tough one to crack.

Answer (score 0):

What about getting it like this:

```
$http({method: 'GET' , url: '/categories'}).success(function(data) {
       $scope.categories = data;
});
```

Comment: my goal is to solve my problem without making huge changes, by that i mean i want solve the problem using $resource unless i fail to find an answer then i can divert from the $resource. Thanks